# Combining three dataframes horizontally in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have three data frames each of shape 100*100 how i combine them horizontally to a new data frame of shape 300*100?
I tried using these commands:

```
result = df1.combine_first(df2) 

result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join_axes=[df1.index])

result = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

But non gave the desired result of a data frame of shape 300*100.
How i can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to combine 3 `100 x 100` `df`s to get an output of `300 x 100`, that implies you want to stack them vertically. So, try `axis=0`.

It might be necessary to rename your columns first, so you could do that in a loop.

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]    
for d in df_list[1:]:
    d.columns = df_list[0].columns
```

---

```
df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: still wrong. it results in 300*300 and half of the values are NAN!

Comment: @sara Check now?